# How do you move a neutron?

Tags: forces, neutrons

An electron can be moved using magnetic field so how about neutron? What really happens at quantum level when you physically move it and what fundamental force is involved? For this question let's ignore gravitational force thanks.

Comment: https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2000/01/neutron-trapping-demonstrated-first-time-nist

Comment: Increase temperature. Neutrons interact with the nuclei of the surrounding material by (elastic) scattering.